# Why won't by tableview load?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a `UITableView` that I am trying to load, but I'm told that the view I'm pushing is nil. Here is my code:

```
    -(IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender
{
    UITableView *rootBeerTableController = [[UITableView alloc] init]; 
    self.rootBeerViewController = rootBeerTableController; 
    [[GlobalData sharedData].mViewManager pushView:ROOTBEER animated:YES]; 
}
```

Can someone tell me why this is? Please let me know if I'm missing some code, I'm new to iPhone, and I'm sorry.

Comment: You usually push a view controller rather than a view. A view is managed by a view controller by means of delegation. Are you sure you are pushing the right thing? What kind of a framework is that?

Comment: 'ROOTBEER` is the name of the `viewcontroller` and I'm trying to push the `viewcontroller` but something tells me that I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: I'll add that in place of the `UITableView` I had `RootBeerTableViewController` but got the same result.

Comment: Saying `ROOTBEER` is the name of the view controller isn't very meaningful. Is it a macro? The name of an instance / static / global variable?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
UITableView *rootBeerTableController = [[UITableView alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain]; 
self.rootBeerViewController = rootBeerTableController; 
[[GlobalData sharedData].mViewManager pushViewController:self.rootBeerViewController animated:YES];
```

Looks like you are pushing a macro that isn't an object... hard to say exactly what is going on as you didn't define what `ROOTBEER` is.